# Accessing fullCalendar JSON customData in dayclick callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Sorry for this most likely simple question. I would like to add some custom `JSON` data to fullCalendar and use it in my dayClick callback function. More specific I want to access and change elements on customData in dayClick. However I could not figure out how to do that. Is it possible without changing the fullcalendar source code?

Thanks a lot in advance
Jens

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    firstDay: 1,
    customData: { foo: 'bar', more: 'baz' },
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        // Within the callback function, this is set to the <td> of the clicked day.
        var t = $(this);
        var foo = customData.foo; // does not work
        customData.more = 'foo'; // does not work

        // Change the day's background color
        if (t.hasClass('badge-important') && foo == 'bar') {
            t.removeClass('badge-important');               
        } else {
            t.addClass('badge-important');              
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are **not** defining a customData variable in any place. The following approach of creating a variable to store your JSON will solve your problem. Check the code below:

```
var customData = {"foo":"bar"};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
....
firstDay: 1,
customData: customData,
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    // Within the callback function, this is set to the <td> of the clicked day.
    var t = $(this);
    var foo = customData.foo; // will now work
    customData.more = 'foo' // will work too

    // Change the day's background color
    if (t.hasClass('badge-important') && foo == 'bar') {
        t.removeClass('badge-important');               
    } else {
        t.addClass('badge-important');              
    }
},
});
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot that worked. I was even able to leave away the "customData: customData" assignment. However I don't understand it. It is obvious that my customData definition does not result in a customData variable. Why not? Why do I have to define the customData variable outside of fullCalendar? The event definitions for fullCalendar are not defined outside. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Well, maybe that is another question, but the answer is simply `scope`. Think the `customData:` as a parameter for an internal function of the fullCalendar. The scope of this parameter would be restrict for this internal function and thus the another internal function `dayClick` wouldn't have access to it. By the way, if an answer is correct mark it as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't know that your problem has been solved. Consider upvoting usefull answers as well. Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I am new to stackoverflow. Sorry I don't have enough karma points to upvote your very helpful answer and comment.

Comment: @Bruno Vieira, Thanks of the answer, i had come across. One more thing, how to render events in fullcalendar?